# Random number in PostgreSQL: 1000 or 2000 (not between)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to randomize two values ​​(1000 and 2000) in a column where each ID will get either 1000 or 2000.
However my logics return a range of numbers between 1000 and 2000.
Is there any way to do this in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get a random number (between 0 and 1), round it (to 0 or 1) then add 1 and multiply by 1000 to get either 1000 or 2000

```sql
select (round(random())+1) * 1000;
```